# Scientific notation with fixed number of fractional digits in Java

Tags: java, decimalformat

I'm trying to use decimalFormat to display decimal numbers in scientific notation after a fixed number of fractional digits like this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.####E0");
System.out.println(df.format(0.2222));
```

In this example, I used the pattern "0.####E0" to set the number of fractional digits to be 4 and the program outputs 2.222E-1.

Now this is what I got for different input values:

```
Five fractional digits: 0.22222 = 2.2222E-1
Six fractional digits: 0.22222 = 2.22222E-1
Seven fractional digits: 0.22222 = 2.22222E-1
```

And so on...

What I want to do is instead of 2.222222E-1, the program should display 2.2222E-3. So any help please and thanks

Comment: But 2.222222E-1 and 2.2222E-3 are different values

Comment: I am voting to close this question as unreproducible...

Comment: Sorry guys, I meant 222.2222E-3

Comment: Don't mix using the point as decimal mark and digit grouping.  [link] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark)

Answer (score 6):

> What I want to do is instead of 2.222222E-1, the program should display 2.2222E-3

No. Your logic is incorrect `E-1` means 10<sup>-1</sup> and for your input `0.2222` you have `2.222E-1` means 2.222 * 10<sup>-1</sup> now you can not have value 2.2222 *  10<sup>-3</sup> *Why?* because than the value would be `0.0022222` and not `0.2222`

> Sorry guys, I meant 222.2222E-3

No. For value `0.2222` you can not have `222.2222E-3` which means 222.2222 *10 <sup>-3</sup> and value will be `0.2222222` which is still different. Moreover have a look at [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) documentation.